# How to get self hosted HTTPS asp.net core site to automatically use certificate bound to port

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, wcf, https

If I bind a certificate to a port (Using *netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0: ...*) - in WCF when self hosting a HTTPS service I don't need to specify the certificate as it automaically finds the certificate as long as I use the same port.

In ASP.NET Core, if I self host a HTTPS endpoint and don't specify a certificate, it throws an exception ('Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. No server certificate was specified').

Is there a way in ASP.NET Core to get it to automatically use a certificate that has already been bound to a port?

Comment: If I remember correctly you can specify a GUID when binding a SSL certificate to a port. Have you used the GUID of your ASP.NET app? That might do the trick.

Comment: I need it to be completely automatic like how WCF does. I'm migrating WCF services to ASP.Net Core and can't add any new configuration items or use GUIDs with certificates

Comment: You can take a look at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/certauth?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: Thanks @TheobaldDu but that article doesn't provide a way to get the certificate registered to a port

Answer (score 2):

So after some research, it seems that *netsh http add sslcert ipport* adds the certificate and port binding to the Http.Sys Windows component

Http.Sys is used by IIS and also WCF, which is why WCF automatically picks up the certificate without having to specify it.

With Asp.net Core, it uses Kestrel which is cross platform and therefore doesn't use the Windows based Http.Sys, so it doesn't automatically get the certificate.

Only solution to this I could find is that ASP.Net Core can run using Http.Sys instead of Kestrel by using the option *UseHttpSys()* when building the host. The downside to this though is it is Windows only and won't work cross platform.

Comment: You can also configure Kestrel to use the cert directly. I didn't post the answer because your question was about nesh specifically.